# How do I know when and when not to include the 'app_name:' in the django url tag

Tags: django

I was writing my first django program, following instructions from a book. The book wrote url tags like `{% url 'learning_logs:index' %}` (learning_logs is the app name) but when I tried to emulate that, I got an error until I went with just `{% url 'index' %}` after reading a post here. Later in my program, after I created another app on the same project called 'users', I was getting the error `Reverse for '' not found. '' is not a valid view function or pattern name` until I reverted to the initial method used in the book, adding "learning_logs:" before the page names `{% url 'learning_logs:index' %}`. I need some help on how to recognise when to add the 'name_of_the_app:' and when not to add it in a url tag.

Here is some code sample with the 'learning_logs:' included:

```
<h1>
    <a href="{% url 'learning_logs:index' %}">Learning Log</a> - 
    <a href="{% url 'learning_logs:topics' %}">Topics</a> -
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        Hello, {{ user.username }}
    {% else %}
        <a href="{% url 'users:login' %}">log in</a>
    {% endif %}
</h1>

{% block content %}{% endblock content %}
```

And here is how I wrote it with just the url name, which also worked sometimes (This was before I created the new app 'users':

```
<h1>
    <a href="{% url 'index' %}">Learning Log</a> - 
    <a href="{% url 'topics' %}">Topics</a> -
</h1>

{% block content %}{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: You should always include an `app_name` if there is one.

Answer (score 1):

in the `urls.py` the function include(that you use to include a new urls.py for an app) has the kwarg `namespace` which define the namespace of the url for the app, that is what you are looking for. The main reason for this is to not collide too commons urls like "list" or "create" between apps. So if you don't define namespace you can just use the name of the url without `namespace:` before.

docs here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces

hope you understand.